# regEx to limix max char length prior to an @ sign

Tags: regex

I want to limit the number of allowable characters prior to a @ sign in an email address. Can a regex be used to serve as a max length type control that will flag 65 characters prior to the @ sign in an email address?

(I never saw regex have length functions... please fill me in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimum of one and a maximum of sixty-five characters:

```
/.{1,65}@/
```

Edit: Check [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) under the *Limiting Repetition* section for more information.